# Why doesn't my rock, paper, scissors give the correct result?

Tags: c++, opengl

The following code is my implementation of rock, paper, scissors. However, the problem is that the moves of the user and computer are not synchronized.

Here's what happened when I executed it:

First there's a choice of the computer (it shows 'paper').
Then when I chose my move (rock) it displayed its move (rock).
This goes for second time (paper v/s rock). 
Then at the third time when I gave my move (scissors) and it gave its move (paper) the result is displayed as 'tied', but I should have won.

I can't understand how the code does this as I had implemented the logic using c++ without the OpenGL part and it worked fine.

Can someone see the problem in the code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>

int a; //GLOBAL VARIABLE TO CHECK USER'S CHOICE IN menu()
int n=0,sa,sb; //n IS NO. OF MOVES WE WANT- WE HAVE 3 MOVES IN THIS PROGRAM. sa & sb ARE THE SCORES OF USER AND COMPUTER RESPECTIVELY 
char ch;

int comp_move();//THIS CALCULATES COMPUTER'S MOVE
void check(int,int);//CHECKS WHO HAS WON/LOST IN ONE PARTICULAR MOVE

int comp_move()
{
    int c=0;
    c=rand()%3;
    if(c==1)drawrock(newrock);
    if(c==2)drawpaper(newpaper);
    if(c==3)drawscissor(newscissor);
    return c;
}

void check(int b)
{
    if(a==1) //rock is player's selection
    {
        if(b==2)sb++;
        if(b==3)sa++;
    }
    else if(a==2) //paper is player's selection
    {
        if(b==1) sa++;
        if(b==3) sb++;
    }
    else //scissor is player's selection
    {
        if(b==1)sb++;
        if(b==2)sa++;
    }
}

void menu(int id) //THE MENU FUNCTION
{
    switch(id)
    {
    case 1: a=1;n++;
            break;
    case 2: a=2;n++;
            break;
    case 3: a=3;n++;
            break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    //glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(a==1)drawrock(rock);
    if(a==2)drawpaper(paper);
    if (a==3)drawscissor(scissor);

    //for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    int b=comp_move();
    check(b);

    if(n==3)//3 rounds
    {
        if(sa>sb)
            sprint(150,450,a);//prints win
        else if(sa==sb)
            sprint(150,450,a);//prints loss
        else
            sprint(150,450,a);//prints tied
    }

    if(n>4) exit(0); //here i want to see the computer's third move
    glFlush();
}

void MYINIT()
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,500,0,500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main()
{
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("rock, paper, scissors");
    glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Rock",1);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Paper",2);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Scissors",3);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
    MYINIT();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Don't just drop your code, please ask a specific question what goes wrong and just add the relevant code. E.g. the opengl code does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i just edited it. hope it helps now. please do reply

Comment: `c=rand()%3;` will yeld a value between `0` and `2`, not `1` and `3`.

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it clearer. If there something wrong feel free to rollback/edit it. Also, try to pick accurate tags. It'll help you attract the right kind of experts to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
c=rand()%3;
```

will yeld a value between `0` and `2`, not `1` and `3`. Replace it with:

```
c = 1 + (rand()%3);
```

Comment: Thank you @didierc . The game works correctly now.